# why do Node.js npm node-cache expire cache not work correctly?

Tags: node.js, api, npm, caching

This method save successfully cache in nodejs

```
    const NodeCache = require( "node-cache" );
    const myCache = new NodeCache( );
    const obj = { online: true,lastactive: '1'};
    const success = myCache.set(`auth@${id}`, obj,7)
    const mykeys = myCache.keys();
```

But when I subscribe expired event it expires all the keys at the same time

```
  myCache.on( "expired", function( key, value ){
  console.log("EXPIRE->",key) });
```